# Equilibrium state and attractor basin for triangular matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have this matrice:
$$M = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-0.2&0&0.1\\
0&0.2&-0.1\\
0&0&0\\\end{array}\right]$$

And this is on of my tasks: Find an equilibrium state and the corresponding attractor basin for this M. Any suggestions?

Comment: First step - calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: HINT - eigenvectors of $M$ are the same as for $10M$ but the eigenvalues are one tenth the size.

Comment: Okay we have this equilibrium: $$=\begin{Bmatrix} 
-0.1x_s\\ 
0.1y_s\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} 
0\\ 
0\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Comment: what would the attractor basin for this one be?

Answer (score 0):

All the eigenvalues of $M$ satisfy $|\lambda_i|<1$ so every point in 3-space will converge to $(0,0,0)$

In general

if $|\lambda_i|>1$ then $M^n v_i$ diverges so any point that is not in the plane perpendicular to $v_i$ will not be part of an attractor basin for any stable fixed point.

if $|\lambda_i|<1$ then $M^n v_i \to (0,0,0) $ and we call $v_i$ a null eigenvector.Any point that is a linear combination of null eigenvectors will be part of an attractor basin for the stable fixed point$(0,0,0)$.

if $\lambda_i = 1$ then $M^n v_i = v_i$ and we call $v_i$ a unit eigenvector. Any point that is a linear combination of unit eigenvectors and null eigenvectors will be part of an attractor basin for the stable fixed point equal to the component of position vector that can be expressed in terms of unit eigenvectors only.